# How to create Docker-Image for c++ executable without having to add all dependencies

Tags: c++, docker, dynamic

I have a programm which I compile on my host machine and want to run it in a Docker-Container.
Now, it needs very many dependencies to run.
First I tried to find out all dependencies with running
`ldd ./my_prog`
and then started copying them to my docker ubuntu image.
But then the copied dependencies need more dependencies such that this did not seem promising if I did not want to copy my whole host system into the container.
Then I read that statically linking my program might cure this.
But since I have a CMake-project I don't know what to do to make it statically link my dependencies. Is this even a valid approach? And if so, how do I do this?

TL;DR: I have a c++ programm which I want to run in a docker-container and try to avoid to copy very many dependencies to the image.

Edit: running my prog with `ldd` gave me a list of dependencies which I extracted all paths from and I copied all these .so files into my container. Yet it still complained of not finding everything.

Comment: Isn't `ldd` recursive?

Comment: See my edit above

Comment: If the libraries exist on your host, don't you simply have to allow your container to mount your host? Or are you trying to create standalone container?

Comment: I looked it up and it seems, that volumes are more for data-purposes, like storing stuff in a database and so on. I am not sure this is the way to go.

Comment: http://blog.oddbit.com/post/2015-02-05-creating-minimal-docker-images/